# Use RTAB-Map with ORB_SLAM2 in ROS

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I successfully compiled RTAB-Map with Orb-Slam2, so I can now choose ORB-SLAM2 as an odometry strategy in RTAB-Map standalone app. Now I would like to use it inside ROS. I guess that maybe it is not implemented yet? Logically, I would expect it to be one of the parameters in rgbd_odometry node. But there is nothing like it in documentation. Or maybe I am wrong and it exists somewhere and I do not know where...

What do you recommend then? Should I launch orb slam 2 in ros and get odometry from tf, which is published by orbslam2 node and use it in rtabmap? Kind of a puzzle for me.

Thank you for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318721/use-rtab-map-with-orb_slam2-in-ros/) by [eMrazSVK](https://answers.ros.org/users/40317/emrazsvk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have successfully built ORB_SLAM2 inside RTAB-Map library and that you could use it with the standalone, you should be also able to use it in ROS through `rtabmap_ros/rgbd_odometry` and `rtabmap_ros/stereo_odometry` nodes. Just set `Odom/Strategy` to 5 and set ORB_SLAM2 vocabulary path with `OdomORBSLAM2/VocPath`:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry">
   ...
   <param name="Odom/Strategy" value="5"/>
   <param name="OdomORBSLAM2/VocPath" value="PATH/TO/ORB_SLAM2/Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt"/>
</node>
```

To see more parameters related to ORB_SLAM2 in RTAB-Map, see [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/7cd7ce3b411538ffb03c4c841d12b494c68de9de/corelib/include/rtabmap/core/Parameters.h#L493-L499) or do

```
$ rtabmap --params | grep ORBSLAM2
```

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0